# At today's price how much would$500 dollars be worth in Bitcoin if it goes to $20,000 dollars again

Tags: buy-bitcoins

Ok you have $500 dollars to invest in Bitcoin at today's price$3,421 dollars and say Bitcoin surges to$20,000 dollars again how much money would you now have.

Comment: `0.146156094709149` Bitcoin

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it is about basic math.

Answer (score 3):

Right this second, bitcoin is at about $3,454. So $500 would get you about 0.145 bitcoins. At $20,000 per bitcoin, that would be worth about $2,900.